# swipeable drawer material ui how to display bottom sheet

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, bottom-sheet, drawer

I'm trying to make bottom sheet using swipeable-drawer https://material-ui.com/ru/components/drawers/#swipeable .

The problem is I need to display bottom sheet with some info  and when user drags, it has to open full content like in the picture below

Here I have found example: https://codesandbox.io/s/ykj8t?file=/demo.tsx  but still I cant display my bottom sheet, I've tried everything. I don't know what I'm doing wrong

And here  my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-sun-i2dh7?from-embed=&file=/src/App.js

[image]

Comment: div with class `MuiPaper-root MuiDrawer-paper MuiDrawer-paperAnchorBottom MuiPaper-elevation16` set `height: 100%`

Comment: @Ergis can't set styles for the drawer. After  drawer close, it rewrites all styles